# Listar na tela Consulta a API REST , JSON no Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Estou com problema  na hora de tratar o retorno de uma solicitação REST.

API: Rails está funcionando corretamente.

minha função

```
 Future <Map> _getProdPromo() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get("http://10.0.2.2:3000/infoPromocao.json");
    List responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
```

Para testar Imprimo via console.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getProdPromo().then((map){
      print(map);
    });
  }
```

Erro:

> flutter (19914): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)]
>   Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type
>   'FutureOr>' E/flutter (19914): #0
>   _ProdutosPromocionaisState._getProdPromo (package:gestoque/produtos_promocionais.dart:19:5) E/flutter (19914):

Faço a Consulta via Advanced Rest e é retornado os seguintes dados:

```
[
    {
        "ad_codprodint": "40011333ME",
        "codprod": 1632,
        "descrprod": "BETONEIRA 400L PRIME MONOF 110V MENEGOT",
        "vlrvenda": 2850
    },
    {
        "ad_codprodint": "40011333ME",
        "codprod": 1632,
        "descrprod": "BETONEIRA 400L PRIME MONOF 110V MENEGOT",
        "vlrvenda": 3130
    },
]
```

Comment: Debugue seu código e nos diga em que momento o erro ocorre e se possível mostre algum exemplo do retorno da sua API.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta com esse retorno do JSON, vamos tentar deixar tudo organizado :D É só você clicar ali no botão **Editar** logo acima dos comentários e acrescentar as informações em sua pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema, é que você recebe um *JSONArray* e tenta tratá-lo como um simples `Map<String, dynamic>`...

No caso você primeiro precisa fazer o decode do seu *JSON* recebido, tendo assim em mãos uma `List<Map<String, dynamic>`, ai sim você consegue pegar os objetos fazendo

```
  Map<String, dynamic> objeto = minhaListaRetornada[0]
```

Criei um exemplo no [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) onde você pode ver a coisa funcionando:

```
import "dart:convert";

void main() {

String json = '[{"ad_codprodint": "40011333ME","codprod": 1632,"descrprod": "BETONEIRA 400L PRIME MONOF 110V MENEGOT","vlrvenda": 2850},{"ad_codprodint": "40011333ME","codprod": 1632,"descrprod": "BETONEIRA 400L PRIME MONOF 110V MENEGOT","vlrvenda": 3130}]';


 Future <List<dynamic>> _getProdPromo() async {
   final result = jsonDecode(json); 

   return result;
  }

_getProdPromo().then((map){
      print(map[1]);
});

}
```

Escrevi um artigo no **Medium** que pode ser útil para você [Descomplicando JSON em Flutter](https://medium.com/flutter-comunidade-br/descomplicando-o-json-em-flutter-47e12b87753b)

Comment: Show de Bola, Consegui resolver o problema, fazendo exatamente isso que me flw.Muito obg, vou ler o artigo